# Maintaining Parent-Child Relationship During XML Serialization/Deserialization

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, parent-child

Is it possible to maintain parent-child relationships when deserializing an XML file where there is a unique identifier in each the parent and child. For example, if the "Name" tag always contains a unique ID what would be the best means of maintaining the parent-child relationship in the following XML:

```
<Building>
    <Name>Bldg 1</Name>
    <Room>
        <Name>Room 1</Name>
        <Table>
            <Name>Table 1</Name>
        </Table>
    </Room>
</Building>
```

In the class there is a property to house the parent node's text value in the "Name" tag, as well as the parent name's tag. For example, the "Room" tag with name "Room 1" would have a property for the parent node's name, which is "Bldg 1" and a property for the parent node's tag, which would be "Building". I don't have control over the schema, but this is a simplified version of the format the data is in.

Comment: Yes, how to plan to PARSE the XML.  Are you going to use de-serialization or do you plan to use other methods?  De-Serialization is used if you are going to build a unique class for each non leaf tag in tge XML (leaves are objects like string, int, DateTime).  If you don't need the class structures you can use other methods like XML Linq to de-serialize the xml.

Comment: I haven't done that much work with XML files and I'm still undecided on how to parse it. I was planning on deserializing to classes and perhaps looking into implementing a base class implementing the IXMLSerializable interface to adjust the read and write methods. Essentially, I have data per the above XML structure that I'd like to deserialize into classes for further manipulation whilst keeping the original parent-child relationship. I'm open with the direction though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not against serialization.  Just showing a different method using XML Linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = 
             "<Root>" +
               "<Building>" +
                  "<Name>Bldg 1</Name>" +
                  "<Room>" +
                    "<Name>Room 1</Name>" +
                    "<Table>" +
                        "<Name>Table 1</Name>" +
                    "</Table>" +
                  "</Room>" +
                  "<Room>" +
                    "<Name>Room 2</Name>" +
                    "<Table>" +
                        "<Name>Table 1</Name>" +
                    "</Table>" +
                  "</Room>" +
               "</Building>" +
               "<Building>" +
                  "<Name>Bldg 2</Name>" +
                  "<Room>" +
                    "<Name>Room 1</Name>" +
                    "<Table>" +
                        "<Name>Table 1</Name>" +
                    "</Table>" +
                  "</Room>" +
                  "<Room>" +
                    "<Name>Room 2</Name>" +
                    "<Table>" +
                        "<Name>Table 1</Name>" +
                    "</Table>" +
                  "</Room>" +
               "</Building>" +
            "</Root>";

            XElement root = XElement.Parse(input);

            var results = root.Descendants("Building").Select(x => new
            {
                name = x.Element("Name").Value,
                rooms = x.Elements("Room").Select(y => new
                {
                    name = y.Element("Name").Value,
                    Tables = y.Elements("Table").FirstOrDefault().Element("Name").Value
                }).ToList()
            }).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: XML Linq is something I looked at , but I thought that it's quite cumbersome for large XML files with many tags. I was hoping to create a base class, which adds control to the read and write XML methods, from which the other classes inherit. I figured this would be a concise option and rather easy to update, but if it's no more simple than using XML Linq then your proposed solution is just as good.

Comment: Some people complain that XML de-serialization is slow, and other complain the Linq is slow and inefficient.  The method you use really depends on a lot of factors.  The size and number of tags in XML , as well as, the number of times you plan to read data.  Without understanding the complete project it is hard to give a recommendation.  My best recommendations is to make the code as simple as possible and make it easy to modify in case you take a different approach.  Also do some bench testing with a small sample of XML to compare different methods.